# Column Chart not Rendering in PDF using ReportViewer Library?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, reportviewer, report-viewer2012

Framework used : .Net Framework 4.5.2
Library used : Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll(Version = 10.0.0.0)

My application is fetching the data from database and binding it to ReportDataSourceCollection.
After that byte[] is returned from Render().
Finally the byte[] is written with fileStream.

Below Function is called
public byte[] Render(string format, string deviceInfo, out string mimeType, out string encoding, out string fileNameExtension, out string[] streams, out Warning[] warnings);

Expected Result : PDF Report contains 1 column chart and table.
Actual Result : Column chart is showing empty with some error on it as in attached image.
& Table is getting populated with data.

Column Chart :

Y-axis : int values like 1375724,67802 etc.
X-axis : string values like 939 - 1571,1572 - 2204 etc.

Investigation :

After my observations I found out that the values in Y-axis are creating problem in not rendering chart.Because by changing the values used for Y-axis chart is rendering.

The values that are creating problem are 3183938 and 2729807.

Can you tell me why the above numbers are creating when rendering to PDF Report ? Any workarounds for such case ?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the RDLC Chart,Y-axis has below Axis options earlier :
Minimum - Auto
Maximum - Auto
Interval - Auto
IntervalType - Number

The values that are creating problem are 3183938 and 2729807.

I changed the above IntervalType property from 'Number' to 'Auto' and the chart is rendered now.